# PrintWriter not printing string, instead printing blank line

Tags: java, io, printwriter

On line 20, the `PrintWriter` does not print the string attached to the 'hold' variable. The 'hold' variable is correct because it prints to the console two lines later with the appropriate string. Any ideas why the `PrintWriter` is printing a blank line?

Code:

```
public void accepter() throws IOException{

    handler han =  new handler();
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(han);  
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(transferFile, true);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fw);

    System.out.println("Reciver started");
    thread2.start();

    while(true){

        aSocket = sSocket.accept();
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(aSocket.getInputStream()));

        hold = input.readLine();

        if(hold != null){

            writer.println(hold);
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println(hold);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, where was `hold` defined?  Second, what if `hold` held an empty `String`?

Comment: Why are you closing your `writer` after writing the first `hold`?

Comment: Luiggi - the second writer has nothing to do with the file. the second one is printing to the console to confirm that hold is being set to the correct string.

Makoto - public String hold;

Comment: Is this your real code? `writer.println(hold)` is going to throw an exception the second time through the loop, because you've closed the `writer`. If that didn't happen, you'd have an infinite loop.

Comment: What *is* the 'string attached to the hold variable'? Why *aren't* you closing the writer on null, and why aren't you closing the socket?

Comment: my apologies, the 'writer.close()' is supposed to be 'writer.flush()'

The string is "test1; test"

Comment: So what is in the file when you eventually close it?

Comment: With the `close()` changed to `flush()`, you have an infinite loop. Once again, is this your actual code?